# Select element in jQuery when one of two possible .data attributes has the desired value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is rather simple but I couldn't find an existing answer:

I want to select a subset of elements if one of their two possible data attributes is "X".

My selector looks currently like this:

```
$('.line').data('identifier1', 'X');
```

I would like to add to the same selector `.data('identifier2', 'X')` using an OR statement, if that's possible with jQuery?

So the result should be that all .line elements are chosen if they have the value 'X' in either their data-identifier1 or data-identifier2.

Here is a snippet with only the OR statement missing:

```js
let myCollection = $('.line').data('indentifier1', "X");

console.log(myCollection);

//myCollection should get divs 1,3,4 but not 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="X" data-identifier2="Y">1</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="Y" data-identifier2="Y">2</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="Y" data-identifier2="X">3</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="X" data-identifier2="X">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `data` attributes like this and use `,` as an `or`.

```js
 let myCollection = $('.line[data-identifier1="X"],.line[data-identifier2="X"]');
 console.log(myCollection);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="X" data-identifier2="Y">1</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="Y" data-identifier2="Y">2</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="Y" data-identifier2="X">3</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="X" data-identifier2="X">4</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and a array to store each div inside

```js
let DivsLine = $('.line');
let myCollection = new Array();

$(DivsLine).each(function(index, value){
  let identifier1 = $(this).data('identifier1');
  let identifier2 = $(this).data('identifier2');
  
  if (identifier1 == 'X' || identifier2 == 'X') {
    myCollection.push($(this).text());
  }
});

console.log(myCollection);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="X" data-identifier2="Y">1</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="Y" data-identifier2="Y">2</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="Y" data-identifier2="X">3</div>
<div class="line" data-identifier1="X" data-identifier2="X">4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, also a good solution but a bit lengthier than the other.

Comment: Yes but i think that my solution is faster to run :)